# Unable to Get Value from Multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
Array ( 
[username] => abc123456, 
[password] => 9876543214, 
[json_input] => [{
"AWB_NUMBER":"8518049",
"ORDER_NUMBER":"TF6E9NRC3J51145",
"PINCODE":"110001"
}]
 )
```

I am unable to get the value of **PINCODE** from **json_input**

> I've tried decoding the **json_input** as it is **encoded**

Comment: WARNING Illegal string offset 'json_input'
WARNING Illegal string offset 'PINCODE'

Comment: Did you already decode the `"json_input"` index from your decoded array?

Comment: Why is it a `String` and not simply in json ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel : Please check the update array. 
**json_input** is **json_encoded**, the rest is NOT **json_encoded**

Comment: Answer for updated Array is `json_decode($array['json_input'],true)['PINCODE']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have json within json.

Assuming your the json string like this:

```
$json_string = '{
    "username": "alpha_bravo",
    "password": "9ynyly89y8uvybiyg87yb",
    "json_input": "[{ 
\"AWB_NUMBER\": \"8542322212\",
\"ORDER_NUMBER\": \"K98S2PUN7H5X125\",
\"PRODUCT\": \"cod\",
\"CONSIGNEE\": \"ABC\",
\"PINCODE\": \"123456\",
\"COLLECTABLE_VALUE\": \"1000\",
\"DECLARED_VALUE\": \"1000\",
\"ACTUAL_WEIGHT\": \"0.74\",
\"LENGTH\": \"12\",
\"BREADTH\": \"5\",
\"HEIGHT\": \"2\",
\"ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION\": {
\"INVOICE_NUMBER\": \"8GC5C190626151125\",
\"INVOICE_DATE\": \"Sun-Sep-2019\"
}
}]"
}';
```

What you want to do first is decode the initial payload like this:

```
$result = json_decode($json_string);
```

Then you want to decode the json input string once again like this:

```
$json_input = json_decode($result->json_input);
```

Now, your *PINCODE* value can be accessed via:

```
echo $json_input[0]->PINCODE;
```

If you are expecting multiple elements in the array of `json_input`, then iterate over it:

```
foreach ($json_input as $item) {
    echo $item->PINCODE . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string has incorrect format, because of wrong double quotes usage in json_input.

You can try to fix it, or just use regular expression to extract needed value:

```
preg_match('/"PINCODE": "(\d+)"/',$inputJsonString, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```